# Print cell from mysql using where and php session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables, where-clause

I have 2 files that are applicable to this question, `myaccount.php` and `test5.php`. 
`test5` connects to MySQL database, and it is supposed to get the contents of one cell and print it out.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("mysql8.000webhost.com", "a5470121_tahahn5", "travis2") or
   die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a5470121_rhs3") or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT `user_name`,`Classperiod1` FROM users
   WHERE user_name ='" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "'"
) or die(mysql_error());  


 $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
 echo   $row['user_name'];

?>
```

the second file `myaccount.php` is supposed to put the printout from the php file in html form

```
<h3> Your First ClassPeriod is<?php echo $row['Classperiod1']?></h3>
```

I've tested this out and using both files with a specific username (ex.John, Andrew etc.) and it will print out the class period fine.  When trying to use `WHERE` with a `SESSION` variable for some reason stops it from printing. It doesn't even show any error messages.
Apologies for any mistakes in the code, or if this is a really stupid question. I'm nearly an absolute beginner where PHP and MySQL are concerned

Comment: It's really bad practice to use usernames. Try using the primary key -user Id instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to remove your mysql details from your question!

Are you starting a session using the `session_start()` function?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

I also don't see where you're setting `$_SESSION['user_name']`

You might try echoing the mysql query you've constructed to see what it contains, this can help find out what's wrong, I'd guess the session variable will be empty.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_name,Classperiod1 FROM users WHERE  user_name ='" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "'";
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I'm using the open osurce php login script http://php-login-script.com/
the my account.php file has more than I showed in my question
myaccount.php
http://pastie.org/2194019
dbc.php(included in myaccount)
http://pastie.org/2194027

Comment: found out the answer
Syntex is fine I forgot 
that in the login.php file $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name 

so changing user name(not session variable) to full_name fixed the query

    sql = "SELECT full_name,Classperiod1 FROM users WHERE  full_name ='" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  

    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    echo   $row['Classperiod1'];

    ?>